# how to grep the following

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have an input file

```
RAKESH_ONE    
RAKESH-TWO
RAKESH123
RAKESHTHREE
/RAKESH/
FIVERAKESH
456RAKESH
WELCOME123
This is RAKESH
```

I would like to get the output

```
RAKESH_ONE
RAKESH-TWO
/RAKESH/
This is RAKESH
```

I want to print the line matching the pattern `RAKESH`. If the pattern is prefixed or suffixed with alphanumeric we should avoid it.

Comment: What options did you try and fail?

Comment: I am trying like     grep -v '[0-9a-zA-Z]RAKESH' which is working for prefixes but it is also printing the non matching pattern lines also like WELCOME123

Comment: grep -w "RAKESH" <file>   ,this is excluding '_' also,but I also want the strings with _ like RAKESH_ONE

Comment: @RakeshTalari: Update the above as part of the question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9]+|^)RAKESH([^a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)
```

This will match patterns on the lines without alphanumeric prefixes or suffixes. It will not match the *whole* line, but if used with `grep` or `sed` you can output just the lines you need.

**UPDATE**

As requested, here's the full `grep` command. Use the `-E` option to use extended regex:

```
grep -E "([^a-zA-Z0-9]+|^)RAKESH([^a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)" file.txt
```

Comment: I see illegal variable name error,when I used with grep